# Adding content based on how long ago a jQuery ajax request was made?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a generic `$.ajax()` request on the page with its repective `success` and `error` parameters, looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: getUrl,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#page").html(data);
        if (slide) {
            $("#page").slideDown(500);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        var data = '<span id="heading">Error</span>'
                  +'<p>The page you requested could not be loaded.</p>';
        $("#page").html(data);
        if (slide) {
            $("#page").slideDown(500);
        }
    } 
});
```

What I'm wondering is, if a request is taking a long time (say, 5 seconds), how can I display some content to tell the user that the request is still active? It might be taking some time due to either a slow webserver or an extremely heavy request or something.

In my case, I'd have a pre-loaded "loading.gif"-type image that I would display on the page. What's the best way to insert it after the request is made?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should display it at the beginning. That's very easy! Read on this: [jQuery: AJAX Preloader](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-Preloader-P974.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout and clearTimeout:

Before making the request:

```
waitId = setTimeout(showWaitIcon, 5000);
```

and on success and error:

```
hideWaitIcon();
clearTimeout(waitId);
```